# Non-reproduceable build fail with gradle-android-test-plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using the gradle-android-test-plugin in [one of my projects](https://github.com/ironjan/MensaUPB). On 3 of 4 machines, `./gradlew --daemon test` is successful. On the other it fails.

The build.gradle is located [here](https://github.com/ironjan/MensaUPB/blob/master/build.gradle), the .travis.yml is here [here](https://github.com/ironjan/MensaUPB/blob/master/.travis.yml). All machines have very similar configurations: the differences I could find are

- different Linux kernels
- different Java build names (i.e. "ArchLinux build 7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64")

After asking on the [project's site](https://github.com/robolectric/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/32), I was recommended to compare my environment configurations and to ask here. I do not know where this issue comes from:

- a bug in my code incl. build.gradle
- an environment configuration (<-- probably this one)
- a bug in the plugin or gradle

Because `./gradlew --daemon test` is the only command that shows this behaviour (the other behave consistent on different PCs), I don't really know where to look further. The stacktrace below causes the build to fail:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMediaStore.reset(ShadowMediaStore.java:27)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.reset(Robolectric.java:1351)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.resetStaticState(ParallelUniverse.java:47)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:226)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    ... 7 more
```

It is thrown when the following test is executed.

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SanityTest {

    @Test
    public void sanity(){
        int i=1;
        assertEquals("insanity!", 2, i+1);
    }

}
```

for completeness, the java configurations below:

```
FAIL$ java -version; javac -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (ArchLinux build 7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
javac 1.7.0_55

SUCCESS1$ java -version; javac -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (suse-8.32.5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
javac 1.7.0_51

SUCCESS2$ java -version; javac -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (ArchLinux build 7.u55_2.4.7-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
javac 1.7.0_55

TRAVIS$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
TRAVIS$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51
```

I also hava checked the output of `./gradlew --version` but did not find a relevant difference:

```
SUCCESS1
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.14.4-1-ARCH amd64

SUCCESS2
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.14.4-1-ARCH amd64

FAIL
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.10.40-1-MANJARO amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have faced this problem recently, and I solve the problem as below.

1. remove ~/.m2 directory if exists
2. remove ~/.gradle/cache if exists

then the test will work!